# Authority create table on custom schema

Tags: sql-server

My default schema dbo.

I not give my users permission to create table.

User authority ; **datareader,datawriter**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.newtable ...
```

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'DB'

But, my users i want to be able to create a table in the other schema. How can I do that?

```
CREATE TABLE support.newtable ...
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- `Create DB Role [db_support]`

2- `GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::support TO [db_support] DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [db_support]`

3- `GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [db_support]`

4- `CREATE TABLE sup.asd (asd int)`

> Command(s) completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

you need to deny permission on a schema level not at the database level.

please refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/ms176128.aspx) MSDN article.

for your scenario it would look like

```
DENY CREATE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO 'user'
```